Eclipse + Encoding + Gitlab
Some of our co-workers use Eclipse as an IDE, which has a built-in implementation of Git (called EGit / JGit). JGit does not support all of native Git's gitattributes.
Our git repository contains files with non UTF-8 encodings, e.g. the legacy windows-1252.
We use a self-hosted GitLab instance for CI. In the diff of the merge request, the GitLab UI does not show special characters (like German umlauts äöü). The only solution proposed by GitLab is to use working-tree-encoding which is not supported by EGit. (I tested the working-tree-encoding in .gitattributes and Eclipse really had problems.)
Is there a nice solution to this?
See also https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/git_attributes.html#support-for-mixed-file-encodings

Does setting the character encoding inside Eclipse for the specific files do anything?

IMO there're only 2 alternatives: 1) convert all files to UTF-8 and always store all files in UTF-8; 2) Use Git instead of EGit and allow Git to convert the files back and forth.

EGit is open source and I would expect your company to provide a pull request for this feature needed by your company or pay someone to do so.

@dan1st: no, since the "working-tree-encoding" setting has the consequence that all files in the repository are saved in UTF-8. But on our local workspace we need to have it in windows-1252 (because of our build tools...)

I meant that you change the encoding in Eclipse for individual files.
